# std::variant reflection. How can I tell which type of value std::variant is assigned?

Tags: c++, reflection, std, variant, type-erasure

I have a class called `foo_t` that has a member called `bar` which could be any one of the types `std::string`, `int`, `std::vector<double>`, etc. I would like to be able to ask `foo_t` which type `bar` has been assigned to. I decided to use `std::variant`.

I've written a solution, but I'm not sure if this is a good use of std::variant. I'm not sure if it matters, but I expect the list of types to possibly grow much bigger in the future. I made an enum class to store which type std::variant is assigned to. My first implementation also available on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pLshfzdpmv177KQf):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

enum foo_kind_t {
  double_list,
  name_tag,
  number,
  unknown
};

template <typename val_t>
struct get_foo_kind_t {
  constexpr static foo_kind_t value = unknown;
};

template <>
struct get_foo_kind_t<int> {
  constexpr static foo_kind_t value = number;
};

template <>
struct get_foo_kind_t<std::string> {
  constexpr static foo_kind_t value = name_tag;
};

template <>
struct get_foo_kind_t<std::vector<double>> {
  constexpr static foo_kind_t value = double_list;
};

class foo_t {

public:

  foo_t(): kind(unknown) {}

  template <typename val_t>
  void assign_bar(const val_t &val) {
    static_assert(get_foo_kind_t<val_t>::value != unknown, "unsupported assignment");
    kind = get_foo_kind_t<val_t>::value;
    bar = val;
  }

  foo_kind_t get_kind() {
    return kind;
  }

  template <typename val_t>
  val_t get_bar() {
    if (get_foo_kind_t<val_t>::value != kind) {
      throw std::runtime_error("wrong kind");
    }
    return std::get<val_t>(bar);
  }

private:

  foo_kind_t kind;

  std::variant<
    int,
    std::string,
    std::vector<double>
  > bar;

};

template <typename val_t>
void print_foo(foo_t &foo) {
    std::cout << "kind: " << foo.get_kind() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value: " << foo.get_bar<val_t>() << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char*[]) {

    // double_list
    foo_t b;
    std::vector<double> b_val({ 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 });
    b.assign_bar(b_val);
    std::cout << "kind: " << b.get_kind() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value: vector size: " << b.get_bar<std::vector<double>>().size() << std::endl << std::endl;

    // name_tag
    foo_t d;
    std::string d_val("name");
    d.assign_bar(d_val);
    print_foo<std::string>(d);

    // number
    foo_t c;
    int c_val = 99;
    c.assign_bar(c_val);
    print_foo<int>(c);

    // unknown
    foo_t a;
    std::cout << a.get_kind() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a good way to do it? Is there a way having better performance? Is there a way that requires less code to be written? Is there a way that doesn't require C++17?

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: I have a tree that holds a bunch of nodes of type `foo_t` with each containing 0 or more of their own children of type `foo_t`. I would like to traverse this tree while drawing an user interface based on those nodes. I know I could use the visitor pattern for that, but I still want to be able to dynamically get the type.

Comment: [`std::variant::index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index)

Comment: std::holds_alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution with type traits

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <type_traits>
    #include <variant>
    
    using MyVariant = std::variant<int, std::string>;
    
    enum class MyVariantType { integer, string };
    
    template <MyVariantType Type, typename T> struct is_variant_type : std::false_type {};
    
    template <> struct is_variant_type<MyVariantType::integer, int        > : std::true_type {};
    template <> struct is_variant_type<MyVariantType::string , std::string> : std::true_type {};
    
    template<MyVariantType VT>
    bool check_variant_type(const MyVariant& myvar)
    {
        return std::visit([&](const auto& arg) { 
            return is_variant_type<VT, std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>>::value;
        }, myvar);
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        MyVariant a = int(10);
        MyVariant b = "Hello";
    
        std::cout << check_variant_type<MyVariantType::integer>(a);
        std::cout << check_variant_type<MyVariantType::integer>(b);
    
        std::cout << check_variant_type<MyVariantType::string>(a);
        std::cout << check_variant_type<MyVariantType::string>(b);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 39):

If you only need to ask "Is this variant of type X ?" for a single type X, then I recommend that you prefer [std::holds_alternative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative) over [std::variant::index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) because the line of code is easier to read and will not have to be updated if the index of the type in the variant changes in the future.

Example:

```
if (std::holds_alternative<X>(my_variant)) {
    std::cout << "Variant is of type X" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Much better then using index what has a lot of side effects when std::variant templates parameters will be changed.

Answer (score 23):

Using [std::variant::index](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) to check stored type at runtime.